# JS: Filter list of objects to include only the strings found in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects similar to the following:

```
let array = [
{
id: 1,
name: Foo,
tools: [{id:3, toolname: Jaw},{id:1, toolname: Law}]
},
{
id: 2,
name: Boo,
tools: [{id:2, toolname: Caw}]
},
{
id: 3,
name: Loo,
tools: [{id:3, toolname: Jaw}, {id:4, toolname: Maw}, {id:6, toolname: Taw}]
}
]
```

I have a second array that looks like the following:

```
let secondarray = ['Jaw', 'Taw']
```

How can I return a list of objects that include only BOTH of the items in the second array? So if an object only has one of the two, the object would not be included. In addition, if the object contains other `tools` not in the `secondarray`, but includes both items in the `secondarray`, it should still be included.

Thus the expected output of this filter would be:

```
{
id: 3,
name: Loo,
tools: [{id:3, toolname: Jaw}, {id:4, toolname: Maw}, {id:6, toolname: Taw}]
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the data array and then check if all of the reqired tools are in the actual object.

```js
let array = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo', tools: [{ id: 3, toolname: 'Jaw' }, { id: 1, toolname: 'Law' }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Boo', tools: [{ id: 2, toolname: 'Caw' }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Loo', tools: [{ id: 3, toolname: 'Jaw' }, { id: 4, toolname: 'Maw' }, { id: 6, toolname: 'Taw' }] }],
    required = ['Jaw', 'Taw'],
    result = array.filter(({ tools }) =>
        required.every(v => tools.some(({ toolname }) => toolname === v))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach to omit the loop over `tools` more than once by using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
let array = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo', tools: [{ id: 3, toolname: 'Jaw' }, { id: 1, toolname: 'Law' }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Boo', tools: [{ id: 2, toolname: 'Caw' }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Loo', tools: [{ id: 3, toolname: 'Jaw' }, { id: 4, toolname: 'Maw' }, { id: 6, toolname: 'Taw' }] }],
    required = ['Jaw', 'Taw'],
    result = array.filter(({ tools }) => 
        required.every(
            Set.prototype.has,
            new Set(tools.map(({ toolname }) => toolname))
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thanks so much for your help!